# Bootstrap generate fixed width col, but just for large displays, for smaller displays responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to generate a fixed width col for big displays with bootstrap, but it should be reponsive if you use it on smaller ones.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3"></div> <-- this should be fixed width 400px for big displays
<div class="col-md-9"></div> <-- content should be always responsive
</div>
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: can you explain the question more....

Comment: On the left side there will be the navigation. this div should be fixed width (400px) for an resolution of, lets say, 900px. 

on the right side there will be a picture galery. I would like to have the left side fixed width for big displays, but if its gets smaller, it should go to 100% width, and the gallery should be under the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS media queries to add fixed width to them.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: i used this for the left div:

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    .fixed{
        width: 400px;
    }
}

The Problem is, that the div with col-md-9 (the right) is swapping to early under the left one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get a fixed-fluid layout in Bootstrap 3 is using @media query that works at the same breakpoint as the Bootstrap media queries. So, in your case use the 992px (md) breakpoint...

```
@media (min-width:992px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
  }
  #main {
    width:calc(100% - 400px);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Bootstrap Fixed-Fluid Layout](http://www.codeply.com/go/3CfoaYfQdG)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3 fixed-size-1"></div> <-- this should be fixed width 400px for big displays

    <div class="col-md-9 fixed-size-2"></div> <-- content should be always responsive
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed-size-1{
//specify height and width
}
.fixed-size-2{
//specify height and width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add responsiveness by using

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"></div> <-- content should be always responsive
```

this will take 9 column in large tab and mobile screen